# How can I remove some files committed to local repo that have not been pushed to remote?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed some data files to my local repo several commits back. I would like to remove these data files from my local without undoing progress in my working copy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+files+from+history

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.

**rebase**

One option is to use `git rebase`.  Suppose your history looks like

```
... x -- o -- A -- B -- C <--(master)
```

where the incorrect adds occurred in `o` (along with, possibly, other changes).  You could then say

```
git rebase -i master~5 master
```

where `master~5` is chosen because, in this example, it is an expression that refers to `o`'s parent.  (You would substitute a similar expression based on the real state of your repo, of course.)

This will bring up a text editor with a TODO list.  Each line in the list will show one of your commits.  Find the entry for commit `o` and change the first word on that line from `pick` to `edit`.  Then save and exit the editor.

After a little processing, you'll get a command prompt.  Remove the unwanted files from the index

```
git rm --cached file/that/shouldn't/be/committed
```

Then continue the rebase.  The only reason there should be conflicts would be if a subsequent commit also edited one of those files, in which case you'll resolve the conflict by again making sure the file is removed from the index.

**filter-branch**

There are some problems with rebase if your "recent history" is complicated.  In the above example, only one ref (`master`) can "see" `o` in its history, and the ref's history back to `o` is linear; so rebase is fine.  But if there are additional branches, or merge commits, then you probably should try something else.

Then you might try `git filter-branch` with an `--index-filter`.  You could write a shell script to do the `git rm` commands.  (This would be similar to above, but you'd want to say

```
git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file/that/shouldn't/be/committed
```

Suppose you write this script and place it at `../index-filter.sh`; and you have a history like

```
                F -- G -- H
               /            \
... x -- o -- A -- B -- C -- M <--(master)
               \
                D -- E <--(feature)
```

Then you could say something like

```
git filter-branch --index-filter ../index-filter.sh -- --all ^master~5
```

where in this case `master~5` is chosen because it refers to `x` (`o`'s parent).  Note we put a `^` before `master~5`; this limits the rewrite to exclude `x` and its history, so you only rewrite back to `o`.

That's potentially important for a few reasons.

First, if you know you haven't pushed `o`, then you aren't rewriting anything that's been shared.  (And anyhow, there's nothing you want to change, even if the same path should happen to appear earlier on, right?)

Also, by limiting the number of commits rewritten, you can help keep `filter-branch` from taking too long (it is a potentially long-running process).

---

There are other options, like the BFG Repo Cleaner; but those are likely overkill for your use case, and one of the above is what I would recommend trying first.

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your commit if they were added to your last commit (`git commit --amend`).

If it was your last commit, create a branch from the previous commit, before you added your files, recreate the commit without the new files, and then rebase the other commits on top of your new commit.

Then delete the old branch and rename the new one.

Comment: unfortunately it was several commits ago.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher. A simpler way would be an interactive rebase from the bad commit

Comment: Indeed, there is the interactive rebase as well. Haven't used it that often, so forgot about this option, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score -5):

Push the commit, take pull, delete the unwanted files, commit, push. -_-

Comment: Absolutely do not push the commit.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @AkshitVerma : Because once the commit is pushed, there will be no reasonable way to purge the files from the remote repository.  Doing what you describe makes those files a permanent part of the repo's history, which is not what OP stated they want.